# how to get node and its childs using node's name and a specific attribute value?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

**note :** i am dealing with xml files that i don't know their structure in advance so i can't use XPath
 here is an example of my xml files :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<HWData>
    <Header time="2013-05-29T13:39:34" uploaded="true" version="1.0" />
    <NE vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" NEId="WBTS-431">
        <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="173" >
            <UNIT vendorName="N" unitId="16" />
            <UNIT vendorName="NOKIA SIEMENS NETWORKS" unitId="225" />
        </EQHO>
        <EQHO vendorName="NSN" equipmentHolderId="40192" >
            <UNIT vendorName="AR" unitId="40267" />
        </EQHO>
    </NE>
    <NE vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" NEId="WBTS-261">
        <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132" >
          <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132-1">
            <UNIT vendorName="NN" unitId="1621" />
          </EQHO>
        </EQHO>
    </NE>
</HWData>
```

i want to know if i can use for example node name "NE" and attribute value NEID="WBTS-261" to have the hole as result!

result expected :

```
    <NE vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" NEId="WBTS-261">
        <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132" >
          <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132-1">
            <UNIT vendorName="NN" unitId="1621" />
          </EQHO>
        </EQHO>
    </NE>
```

can someone put me on the right way to do that any example,idea or suggestion will be appreciated.. 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath. It has a special search language for searching elements in xml. [See this page.](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/)

Comment: The MOID of EQHO is the prefix (in your xml example) of the MOID of UNIT subelements in all cases. Is this not always true? When always true then it is enough to find all the EQHO elements and then list their children. When not always true then the parent MOID prefix check is needed for the UNIT MOID-s. Is this the task to be done?